# .NET 6 project in Visual Studio offers update NuGet packages to 7.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 ASP.NET Core project in VS 2022 and wonder if there is a way not to get .NET 7 packages in my NuGet update list? Or am I supposed to update NutGet packages to 7.0.X? What is the best practice?

[image: NuGet package manager]

Comment: My TFM is .net6.0-windows7.0 and when I update the packages to 7.0.0, there's a warning: ``{PackageName} 7.0.0 doesn't support net6.0-windows7.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net6.0 or later.``
It's there both in visual studio and in the command line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check dependencies for the corresponding packages. For example [`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/7.0.0#dependencies-body-tab) specifies next supported frameworks and dependecies:

- *.NETFramework 4.6.2*

  - Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (>= 7.0.0)
  - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0)
  - System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (>= 4.5.4)
- *.NETStandard 2.0*

  - Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (>= 7.0.0)
  - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0)
  - System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (>= 4.5.4)
- *.NETStandard 2.1*

  - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0)
- *net6.0*

  - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0)
- *net7.0*

  - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 7.0.0)

But for example [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` 7.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/7.0.0#dependencies-body-tab) is only supported only for .NET 7 (my guess would be that either all or almost all ASP.NET Core packages would behave the same way):

- *net7.0*

  - Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 6.15.1)

So while in theory you can upgrade some of dependencies but definitely not all without updating target framework version. In general case I prefer to update either everything to the next major version or nothing (for packages supporting the "tied to runtime" versioning).

Comment: This shows a big problem e.g. with `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 7.0.0`: it's required also under NET 6, but not listed as dependency.  So everything builds fine, but it fails at runtime, once the package is required, else not. This means ugly and unpredictable bugs. Or an annoying reference to MS.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (and possibly others) everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

It's up to you to decide whether you want to upgrade or not. These packages are just *named* V7.0.0, because they where released together with .NET 7.0. For most (if not all) of these packages, there's no requirement that the runtime needs to be .NET 7.0. Just read it as V7.0 *of that package*. You can update (and even use new features) of these packages without updating the runtime of your application.

Comment: I'm afraid there is a very high chance that the AspNetCore ones will need corresponding runtime.

Comment: @GuruStron True, you might be right there. Unfortunately, it's typically just "try or error", since there's no general rule about which ones work and which ones don't. Looking at the dependencies manually (see the other answer) is ugly, too.

Comment: Yep, there is no rule. Though over the years I've developed a rule of thumb for me - at least for web projects (as I wrote in my answer) - for packages which follow the approach of releasing new major package version with the new runtime (usually Microsoft ones) - stick to the major package version which matches the runtime - this way you will not need to get into the breaking changes and other kind of compatibility =)

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely accurate. There is a clear dependency on net7.0 on at least the asp.net ones. Why would they show up in a project targeting .net 6? It predictably fails if you actually attempt the update:

Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 7.0.2 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 7.0.2 supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)`

Comment: @ArianKulp True, there are _some_ cases where it is known,  but even then only after you attempt to install it. It's not currently technically possible to filter incompatible packages in the search already.