# Errors updating project NuGet packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

It'a gotten a little scary to update all my NuGet packages as I always seem to have errors after I do.

I just did this now and had two issues.

1. I'm getting about a dozen of the following error.

   > Warning CS8032 An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.FixAnalyzers.CSharpFixerWithFixAllAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Users\jwood.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll: Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.FixAnalyzers.FixerWithFixAllAnalyzer`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, Version=3.3.3.10305, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
2. I had some compatibility errors and several packages that refused to install. On closer inspection, I see the package manager is trying to install version 7 libraries when my project uses .NET 6. Why would Package Manager want to install incompatible libraries?

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781983/net-6-project-in-visual-studio-offers-update-nuget-packages-to-7-0-0/74782109#74782109) A version 7.0 package is not generally incompatible with .NET 6.0. Some are, but most work just fine (and nuget is unfortunately unable to know).

Comment: @PMF: Yes, you're right. But 7 of them produce incompatibility errors when attempting to upgrade.

Comment: I have not seen this particular error, and I have updated already quite a few packages (not in an ASPNet project, though). So I don't know where that's coming from. When I got errors, it was typically due to problems in Nuget simultaneously updating all projects in the solution correctly. So I always had to manually make sure that all projects used the same versions.