# Update all Nuget Packages to latest version compatible with specific dotnet version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

Currently I have a project consisting of numerous dotnet 3.1 applications / libraries, and we are in the process of upgrading them to dotnet 6 (latest dotnet version with LTS)

Upgrading to dotnet 7 is out of the question and not up to me, I am strictly instructed to upgrade to explicitly dotnet 6.

Unfortunately, simply just opening the Updates pane for nuget in Visual Studio and selecting "Select all packages" and hitting update will default to trying to attempt to update them to the dotnet 7 compatible packages, which then of course fails as the application is using dotnet 6.

Is there any easy method to filter down available packages to *only* dotnet 6 compatible ones, and then updating to the latest of that subset?

This project is quite large and has countless packages in use so, manually going through each of them one by one to handpick the latest compatible version would take a very long time, so if there's a way anyone knows to do this automatically that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781983/net-6-project-in-visual-studio-offers-update-nuget-packages-to-7-0-0/74782109#74782109 answer your question?

Comment: "which then of course fails as the application"... No, that's likely not the reason, as most packages are compatible with 6.0, even though they're _named_ 7.0. What exact error do you get?

Comment: any update of this issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any easy method to filter down available packages to only
> dotnet 6 compatible ones, and then updating to the latest of that
> subset?

I think **the answer is NO.** There doesn't have a easy way to achieve this. Currently, the feature in VS2022 is just update the packages to latest.

As PMF mentioned, most of the packages which support the ".NET7" will also support the ".NET6".

For your requirements, there only have two ways:

1, Write the code yourself, use a technology like python crawler to filter out the latest compatible versions of packages one by one, and then use the script to update the package version in the .csproj file.

2， Since this feature is not supported currently, you can create a feature request:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest